# jQuery not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this jQuery which should 'slide in' a header after scrolling on the page, but nothing happens. At the 3rd line, my code editor gives me a !read only alert, perhaps theres a problem with the syntax?

I'm using beaver builder which calls jQuery automatically.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > 450){
                $('#jQuery-mob').slideDown();
            }

            if (scroll < 450){
                $('#jQuery-mob').slideUp();
            }

        });
    });

        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > 700){
                $('#why-jquery').slideDown();
            }

            if (scroll < 700){
                $('#why-jquery').slideUp();
            }

        });
    });
```

both #jquery-mob and #why-jquery are set to display:none

css:

```
    #why-jquery {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}

#jQuery-mob {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I believe you shouldn't have two `$(document).ready`

Comment: Can you please post your html?

Comment: `scroll < 450 && scroll < 800` one of those two conditions are either redundant or incorrect. Same with these two: `scroll < 700 && scroll < 1000`

Comment: Beaverbuilder only loads their own copy of jQuery if for some reason jQuery is not available or an older version is loaded. You should still declare your own version as this is their fallback. **[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h2eemsa/)** of your scripts working with jQuery declared.

Comment: Your code editor giving you ` !read only ` alert means you don't have write access to the file. Any code you write won't be saved, hence wont run.

Comment: @NathanielFlick that wont be possible as I used a page builder, but I assure you the IDs are correct.

Lixus if that caused the issue, would 1 work and only 1 be broken?

Comment: @AdamBarker no, there's nothing wrong with using two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using beaver builder which calls jQuery automatically.

I think you mean to say:

> I'm using wordpress which calls jQuery automatically.

For wordpress sites you must, by default, use `jQuery` instead of `$`. You can either replace all, or only use jQuery in the .ready "wrapper" and pass the `$` into the .ready function.

Example of both:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 450){
            jQuery('#jQuery-mob').slideDown();
        }

        if (scroll < 450){
            jQuery('#jQuery-mob').slideUp();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(  $  ) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 700){
            $('#why-jquery').slideDown();
        }

        if (scroll < 700){
            $('#why-jquery').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Be aware I did not check your code, but I did see you're using `scroll` without declaring it with `var`. This means `scroll` will be a global variable. Both functions setting/using it could cause interference with each other, as well as overwriting window.scroll function. You may want to use `var scroll=` etc. and also better use another variable name.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. It's also an idea to set a var for $ that = jQuery like this: var $ = jQuery;

Comment: Yeah that's another option.

Answer (score 1):

`scroll` is a window-level function, so in a browser context acts as a [reserved word](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp):

```js
console.log(scroll)
```

You're trying to overwrite it with a variable named "scroll", which is what causes the "!read only" error you're seeing.

Use a different variable name (and declare it using 'var'.)

Answer (score -1):

This code has logical issue

```
  if (scroll < 450 && scroll < 800){
```

When scroll is smaller than 450, it is smaller than 800 as well, so why did you include the second comparison?

The same story on this line:

```
if (scroll < 700 && scroll < 1000){
```

Comment: I've fixed it and updated the OQ but no changes on my page